# Como ordenar array con sort y dos condiciones

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de ordenar un array por dos condiciones a la vez (ambas son fechas)

El caso es que si lo hago de esta manera, **la primera condición si se cumple, pero la segunda nunca**. Y el objetivo es ordenar por ambas.

```
this.data.sort(
    (a, b) => {
        return this.dateFormat(b.fechaInicio) - this.dateFormat(a.fechaInicio) ||
          this.dateFormat(b.fechaFin) - this.dateFormat(a.fechaFin)
    }
);
```

Para dejarlo funcionando, he separado las condiciones, y si que funciona, sin problema, pero no lo veo eficiente.

```
this.data.sort(
    (a, b) => this.dateFormat(b.fechaInicio) - this.dateFormat(a.fechaInicio)
);
this.data.sort(
    (a, b) => this.dateFormat(b.fechaFin) - this.dateFormat(a.fechaFin)
);
```

```
dateFormat(date: string) {
    return date != '' ? new Date(date).getTime() : 0;
  }
```

Y ya **lo** que es **mas curioso**, es que el orden con las dos condiciones probado en cualquier playground JS funciona bien.

Por lo tanto ya, vengo a ver si me podéis aportar algo de luz, alguien que ya haya pasado por aquí.

Ya os digo, que ahora me funciona, pero me gustaría saber el pq no funciona el *sort* con las dos condiciones.

Comment: Por favor, presiona [edit] y agrega a tu pregunta, un ejemplo grupo fechas, el resultado esperado y el código de la función `dateFormat`. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo ordenas por ambas? En base de datos cuando ordenas por dos campos se ordena por el primero y, en caso de tener el mismo valor, se ordena por el segundo.

Comment: Si, para poder ayudarte es de vital importancia saber que hace `dateFormat` y que devuelve

Comment: Función añadida a la pregunta

Comment: @Diego, ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo de fechas y el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 0):

Mi forma de ordenación, que creo que es a la vez eficiente, legible y fácil de alterar para más condiciones (no sólo 2) es la siguiente, adaptándolo a las propiedades necesarias:

```
miarray.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (b.fechaInicio > a.fechaInicio) return 1;
    if (b.fechaInicio < a.fechaInicio) return -1;

    if (b.fechaFin > a.fechaFin) return 1;
    if (b.fechaFin < a.fechaFin) return -1;
});
```